# How to get MySQL database to stop repeatedly turning itself off and on?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I am running a local MySQL database on my Macbook, and when it works it works. But every once in awhile, it will have turned itself off. Then when I start it again, it will repeatedly stop and start itself every few seconds or so. If I stop it manually and start it again, it repeats the cycle.

How can I get it to stay on? What could be causing this? I have connected to it through Python and also use my terminal to access it, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: That should not be happening.  Anything in the logs?  How much RAM?  What is in my.cnf?

Comment: @RickJames Hm... I don't see logs or my.cnf in the mysql-8 folder. I have 4GB of RAM and MySQL appears to be using about 310MB of it.

Comment: Perhaps mysqld.err or mysql.log.

Comment: @RickJames Hm... it doesn't look like it. When I came back to my laptop, MySQL was running consistently, but then I kept getting error

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

And when I tried to restart the server, it is turning itself off and on again.